# App doesn't run on physical device

Tags: java, android

I'm creating my first app but when I install the apk file in my device, it crashes when I try to open it. I can't find the problem, so I'll post the beginning of the code. The app starts with a SplashActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

then the Home Activity should start

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    getIntent();

    String[] names= new String[]{"Albums","By Era", "Members", "Eddie", "Fan Arts", "Ed Force One"};
    int []imageId = new int[]{R.drawable.albums, R.drawable.era, R.drawable.members, R.drawable.eddie, R.drawable.fanarts, R.drawable.edforceone };

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid( Home.this, names, imageId);
    final GridView grid_main = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_main);
    grid_main.setAdapter(adapter);

    grid_main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // selection
            String maincat="";
            switch (grid_main.getCheckedItemPosition()){
                case R.id.albums:
                    maincat="Albums";
                    break;
                case R.id.era:
                    maincat="By Era";
                    break;
                case R.id.member:
                    maincat="Members";
                    break;
                case R.id.eddie:
                    maincat="Eddie";
                    break;
                case R.id.arts:
                    maincat="Fan arts";
                    break;
                case R.id.ed:
                    maincat="Ed Force One";
                    break;

            }
            //start different activities
            if ( maincat.equals("Eddie") || maincat.equals("Ed Force One") || maincat.equals("Fan arts")){
                Intent intent= new Intent(Home.this, Pictures.class);
                intent.putExtra("maincat", maincat);
                startActivity(intent);}
            else {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Home.this, SubActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("maincat", maincat);
                startActivity(intent);}
        }

    });

}
@Override
// overflow menu
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            Intent intent= new Intent(Home.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.contacts:
            Intent intent2= new Intent(Home.this, Contacts.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the part of the manifest regarding the activities

```
<activity android:name=".Home">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SubActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Contacts"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Pictures"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewPic"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The app has a huge assets folder but even deleting it, the app doesn't run. I verified the minimun sdk version (19) is the same as my Android device version (4.4). It must be said that I can't use the Android Studio emulator because my hardware is obsolete :/

Comment: For your phone to appear on Android Studio, go to Settings - About phone, and  tap many times on Build number. Go back to Settings and you should see a new Developer options menu item. Enter there and enable USB debugging

Comment: thanks @LeonardoAcevedo

Answer (score 1):

I can't post comments so I have to use the asnwers.

What does this mean `I can't even test on my device because it doesn't have the option to do so` ? Why can't you test it from Android Studio ?

Apart from that, a lot of code is missing. There are many `Activity` in the `Manifest` but you only posted 2, and it looks like `onCreate` of `Home` isn't complete.

Comment: Now you should be able to comment

Comment: At least those that deserved it ;-) I thought you should be able to comment without having to risk a -1 by "misusing" answers for comments

Comment: @Marged Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: There are many activities and I can't post all the code. Anyway, where should Home be incomplete? I'm new to Android so maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @DoctorWatson I meant, that there is no code in `onCreate` of `Home`, what I guess you forgot to post. Or is it in fact empty ?

Comment: @JonZarate there's a lot of code afterward, but it's just a series of strings and custom adapters

Comment: @DoctorWatson That code can also lead to errors that make the app crash

Answer (score 0):

**Change in SplashActivity.class :**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }
        }, 1000);

}
}
```

**Change in AndroidManifest :**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
<activity android:name=".Home"/>
```

**Change in Home.class :**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
       ****Your code*****

    }
}
```

Comment: do I have to  put a getIntent() in Home Activity or not?

Comment: you can pass data from one activity to next activity then use getIntent().

Answer (score 0):

You directly started your activity in `onCreate`, try to put a button and apply `onClick` method on that to open your new activity. like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @override
    public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Instantiate your button before this code.

Comment: in which activity you say?